# Creating an object oriented tkinter program: Trying to pass a string value to a method defined in a separate class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create an object oriented tkinter program. As of now, I have written 4 classes. Class 1 is the main program, Class 2 is the home frame, Class 3 is the AlumniSearch frame, and Class 4 is the AlumniProfile display frame, where the frame displays all the information that is compiled in the imported class called "alumniProfile".

My goal is to use a string value selected in the "alumniSearch" class to update/change the object created in the "alumniProfiles" in order to display the object on the "alumniProfiles" page.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from personClass import alumniProfile

class alumniSearch(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, **kwargs)

        self.searchBox = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.searchBox.grid(row=1, column=1)

        searchButton = ttk.Button(self, text='Go', command=self.searchAlumni)
        searchButton.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.selectedResult = tk.StringVar()
        self.resultsBox = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.selectedResult, width=30)
        self.resultsBox.pack(side='left', fill='x')

        viewProfileButton = ttk.Button(self, text='View Alumni Profile', command=self.passName)
        viewProfileButton.pack(side='left')

    def passName(self):
        selectedName = ''
        for i in self.resultsBox.curselection():
            selectedName = self.resultsBox.get(i)
        
        # need something here to pass the selectedName to the self.alumniPerson object in alumniProfiles class


class alumniProfiles(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container, controller, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(container, **kwargs)
        
        self.selectedName = 'Mr. Bryan B. Kornegay Jr.'  # default name until another name is 
        # selected in alumniSearch class
        self.alumniPerson = alumniProfile(self.selectedName)  # builds object using the name given
        personValues = self.alumniPerson.compileValues()  # initializes the method to create the label

        self.valuesVariable = tk.StringVar()
        self.valuesVariable.set(personValues)

        self.displayValues = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.valuesVariable)
        self.displayValues.pack(side='left')


    def setName(self, name):  # needs to dynamically update the label displayed on the page
        self.selectedName = name
        self.valuesVariable.set(name)
        return self.valuesVariable
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that illustrates the problem — not your whole program.

Comment: Didn't realize how much of a mess that was lol thank you

Comment: That's still not a [mre]. Post something runnable along with instructions, if needed, on how to make the problem apparent / cause it to happen.